# ES6 features complient

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Hi I am having problems to change require to import statements. My all files are supporting arrow functions and const, let etc. Just when I change require statements to import I am having lot of trouble.

Following are my files:

My Grunt file:

```
const request = require('request');
const webpackConfigDev = require('./webpack.config.dev');
const webpackConfigProd = require('./webpack.config.prod');

module.exports = function init(grunt) {
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  const reloadPort = 35729;
  let files;

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    eslint: {
      target: ['app/**/*.js', 'clientSide/**/*.js', 'config/**/*.js',
        'test/**/*.js', 'app.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
    },
    webpack: {
      options: {
        stats: !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
      },
      prod: webpackConfigProd,
      dev: Object.assign({ watch: true }, webpackConfigDev),
    },

    mocha_istanbul: {
      coverage: {
        src: 'test/**/*.js',
        options: {
          check: {
            statements: 85,
            functions: 85,
            branches: 77,
          },
          excludes: [
            'app.js',
            'config/*',
            'migrations/xyz/*',
            'app/models/*',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    mochaTest: {
      test: {
        options: {
          quiet: false,
          noFail: false,
        },
      },
      src: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
    },
    develop: {
      server: {
        file: 'app.js',
      },
    },
    stylus: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'public/css/style.css': 'public/css/style.styl',
        },
      },
    },


  grunt.config.requires('watch.js.files');
  files = grunt.config('watch.js.files');
  files = grunt.file.expand(files);

  // Load the npm dependencies into grunt
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-istanbul');

  // Load webpack plugin npm tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');

  grunt.registerTask('delayed-livereload', 'Live reload after the node server has restarted.',
    () => {
      const done = this.async();
      setTimeout(() => {
        request.get(`http://localhost:${reloadPort}/changed?files=${files.join(',')}`,
          (err, res) => {
            const reloaded = !err && res.statusCode === 200;
            if (reloaded) {
              grunt.log.ok('Delayed live reload successful.');
            } else {
              grunt.log.error('Unable to make a delayed live reload.');
            }
            done(reloaded);
          });
      }, 500);
    });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'env:test',
    'eslint',
    'mocha_istanbul',
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'env:dev',
    'eslint',
    'stylus',
    'webpack',
    'mocha_istanbul',
    'develop',
  ]);

  // The default task just runs the project on dev
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'build',
    'watch',
  ]);
};
```

I just changed from const to import in my .js file but this is not running. When running for coverage then all the problem starts.
Please help me out. I have been trying to solve this from 2 days.

Comment: FYI you probably want `import mysql from 'mysql';`, not `import * as mysql from 'mysql';` since `module.exports` is conceptually the "default" of a CommonJS module.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it is the same error. Unexpected token import

Comment: Yup! I left this as a comment because it's just a suggestion in general, not an answer to your question. The others have already covered that.

Comment: Please post the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: yups posted it.

Comment: So what are you expecting that `glob.sync` logic to do? Are you trying to run your JS code in Node, the browser, or both? If you're using `import` statements in your code that you run in Node, things get pretty complicated, but using `import` statements that just run in the browser already work automatically via Webpack.

Comment: yeah actually I am trying to run import with the server side.

Comment: I have edited the question and presented in a more refined way. Can anybody tell where the problem might be.

Answer (score 3):

If you are adventurous and really want to use Modules in Node.js, there is a way.
[Node.js 8.5 added *experimental* support for ES Modules](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V8.md#2017-09-12-version-850-current-mylesborins). The documentation on how to use it can be found in [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/esm.html). Here are the essentials:

- Use Node.js 8.5 or higher
- Use the `--experimental-modules` flag
- Use the `.mjs` extension on your module files

Comment: http://node.green is an excellent quick reference to see which version of Node supports which ES6 (a.k.a ES 2015) feature. ES6 usage a is really bad idea in anything less than Node v6.x.

Answer (score 0):

While `import` is part of ES6, it is not yet supported in NodeJS, and has only very recently became available in browsers. So you will have to keep your `require` statements. See [this](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/53) for further info

Comment: But there must be a way, maybe by some tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

use babel loader and presets in you webpack config for transpiling es5 to es6. [Essentially](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/248c919360516d8894ea27ff01e5165051a66224/tools/webpack.config.js#L74)

Further, make a webpack entry for server also. At present, you are using webpack for client only, hence servere code is not getting transpilled. Server config will be similar. Please follow the link, and specifically make following changes in its values

```
target: 'node',

  entry: {
    server: ['babel-polyfill', './src/server.js'],
  }
```

Comment: If the code is running on Node, using it via Webpack is very roundabout. You don't need Webpack to use Babel.

Comment: OP is already using webpack in his sample code. Also, if OP is adamant to use import in node, then transpiling to es5 is the only option.

Comment: I have uploaded my webpack file and it is already using babel. Still same issue persists.

Comment: Hmm, then there must be more to this, because Webpack already understands `import` without Babel anyway. `Unexpected token import` is a Node error, not a Webpack one.

Comment: you mean after continuation for target: web I should put the above entry?

Comment: you need to send webpack in grunt as an array of two webpack configs, webpack.client.js and webpack.server.js. webpack.client.js you can use yours, make another similar entry for  webpack.server.js with target as node and entry as server.js

Comment: I really appreciate your guidance Shishir. But I am bit confused here. Can you give an example or can you show the proper modifications in the above files?